# How to increment a value of y based on x in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, increment

I know this is a simple question but I am quite new to coding. I want an if function that determines Y from the value of X like so:

> if the value of x is 1.5, then y is 20. For every 0.1 deviation in x, lower the value of y by 0.3

So if x is 1.5, y will be 20. If x is 1.6, y will be 19.7. If x is 1.3, y will be 19.4, and so on.

I have started this

```
if (x = 1.5){
    y = 20;
}  else {

    }
```

How should I complete this function ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and read up on [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). After doing some research and [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, try it yourself. If you're stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and note exactly where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question correctly, this is a math problem? Is : y = 20 - Math.abs((x - 1.5)  * -3) what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be as follows:

```
if (x == 1.5) {
    y = 20;
} else {
    y = 20 - Math.abs((x - 1.5) * 3);
}
```

Or as @lamonde mentioned, to simplify the equation, you can avoid the conditional statement all together as you will get the same result if `x = 1.5`:

```
y = 20 - Math.abs((x - 1.5) * 3);
```

Comment: The "if" part is useless, the else will return 20 when x is equal to 1.5.

Comment: @Lamonde True, thanks. Updated my answer to include that statement.